# Compare values calculated from two strings

Tags: swift

Two people participate in competition. There will be one easy, difficult and medium question.

Scores per difficulty:

- E: 1
- M: 3
- H: 5

User will enter two strings (A and B) and function should find out greater score or tie.

```
func winner(A: String, B: String) -> String {

     var sumA = 0
     var sumB = 0
     var sumhigh = 0

     var checker: Bool = false 
     for i in 0..<(A.count-1) {
         if (erica[i] == "E") {
            sumA += 1
            checker = true
         } else if (A[i] == "M"){
            sumA = sumA + 3
            checker = true
         } else if (A[i] == "H"){
            sumA += 3
            checker = true
         }
     }
     return String(sumA)
}

print(winner(A: "EHH", B: "EME"))

Desired result : A Wins // How to achieve this
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's not clear what your question is. This appears to be a homework problem and solution. Is there a problem with your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will compare the two strings to determine a winner.

```
func checkWinner(aString: String, bString: String) -> String {

    // Make lowercase for comparison, so that input case does not matter
    let a = aString.lowercased()
    let b = bString.lowercased()

    // Dictionary of values
    let scoreDict: [Character : Int] = ["e": 1, "m": 3, "h": 5]

    // Score variables to increment
    var aTotal = 0
    var bTotal = 0

    // Calculate scores
    for char in a {
        aTotal += scoreDict[char] ?? 0
    }
    for char in b {
        bTotal += scoreDict[char] ?? 0
    }

    // Calculate winner
    if aTotal == bTotal {
        return "It’s a draw"
    } else {
        return aTotal > bTotal ? "A wins! Score: \(aTotal)" : "B wins! Score: \(bTotal)"
    }
}

// Here is an example in which A wins
print(checkWinner(aString: "ehh", bString: "meh"))
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
func phraseValue(sentence: String) -> Int
{
  var count = 0
  for letter in sentence
  {
    if letter == "E"
    {
        count += 1
    }
    else if letter == "M"
    {
        count += 3
    }
    else if letter == "H"
    {
        count += 5
    }
  }
 return count
}
```

and finally

```
func winner(A: String, B: String) -> String {

     var sumA = 0
     var sumB = 0

     sumA = valuePhrase(sentence: A)
     sumB = valuePhrase(sentence: B)

     if sumA == sumB
     {
        return "tie"
     }
     else if sumA > sumB
     {
        return String(sumA) + "A wins"
     }
     else
     {
        return String(sumB) + "B wins"
     }
}
```